# Elliptic operators corresponds to non vanishing vector fields

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ds.dynamical-systems, elliptic-pde, differential-operators, index-theory

> **Added, June 19, 2019:**   The  main  motivation of  this  post is  to  associate an  index  to  differential operator  associated to  a  dynamical  system such that the index  has  an interesting  dynamical interpretation. For  example we  hope that  the  index can help  us  to  find  an  upper  bound for the  number of  attractors  of  a dynamical  system.   According to  comment  conversations in this post we realize  that ellipticity or  hypoelipticity is  a very relevant or  perhaps  a  necessary  conditions  for  existence of  "Index".  Now  the  subject and  materials  of  this recently hold  conference, ["Fredholm theory of  Non  elliptic  operatores](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmtast/Leeds-FTNO-2019/) seems to be  related to this  post.

Let $X$ be  a  non vanishing  vector  field on  a compact  manifold $M$. The only differential operator associated with $X$ which I am aware of, is the derivational operator $D(g)=X.g$. Unfortunately this operator is not an elliptic operator.

From the  dynamical view point,what type of **elliptic** operators, or  at  least  Fredholm diff. operators, can be associated with $X$?

I mean, for  a  given non vanishing vector  field $X$, what interesting elliptic operator $D$ can be constructed such that its  fredholm index contains some information about the dynamical behavior of $X$. For example: the number of attractores, or the number of isolated compact invariant sets, etc..

**EditL:** For  a  possible related post see the following:

[How to compute the index of such operator?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143556/how-to-compute-the-index-of-such-operator)

Comment: The Laplacian plus the operator you mention is an elliptic operator associated with the vector field. Do you want the operator to be of first order or to depend linearly on the vector field? Any additional assumptions would help.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Ah! I realy thank you very much for your comment. As you said $\Delta +D_{X}$ is a an elliptic operator.Now my next question is "what is the dynamical interpretation for the fredholm index of this ellitic operator". My main motivation: The codimension of the range of derivational operator is  an upper bound for the number of limit cycles of $X$. But two difficulities: D is not  elliptic the second $D$ is  not fredholm in the case of existence of  a  limit cycle surrounding a non resonance singularities. Thanks again for your interesting comment. I wrote a related motivation in

Comment: ...in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164059/codimension-of-the-range-of-certain-linear-operators

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta  do you think there are some  dynamical interpretation for the  fredholm index of the  elliptic operator which you proposed? What about if the  laplacian correspond to  a  metric  which  has some compatibility with $X$? By compatibility I mean some situation like thihttp://mathoverflow.net/questions/160945/limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesicsgeodesiable-flows:

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by a dynamical interpretation, but my first intuition is to consider the Hamiltonian flow associated with the operator. The flow associated with the Hamiltonian is the geodesic flow (a free particle), and the extra term adds a force described by the vector field to the equations of motion. I am not familiar enough with the Fredholm index in this context to be able to say anything meaningful about it.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta   By  dynamical interpretation, I mean , for example"The number of  attractors of $X$" In the  second  part of this  note I explained some thing related to this concept http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0001. In this  note  I tried to make  a remedy for  non elliptic ness of the derivational operator. But what do you mean by "Hamiltonian flow associated with the operator"?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta As another example of  dynamical interpretation for certain diff operator see the  Veku theorem in  .(Topology and analysis, the Atiyah-Singer index formula and gauge-theoretic

physics, by B. Booss and D. D. Bleecker)

Comment: The $C^\infty(M)$-algebra of scalar differential operators generated by $L_X$, the Lie derivative along $X$, contains no elliptic operator if $\dim M>1$.

Comment: Consider the Hamiltonian function $H:T^*M\to\mathbb R$ defined by $H(x,p)=\frac12g_{ij}(x)p^ip^j+X_i(x)p^i$. The corresponding Hamiltonian flow on the cotangent space is a dynamical system corresponding to $X$. If $X=0$, you get geodesics. A simpler dynamical system corresponding to $X$ is the system $\dot x=X(x)$ on $M$, but this does not look "as elliptic" as the Hamiltonian one. Do you want the dynamical system to live on $M$ itself rather than $T^*M$? The dynamical viewpoint would be clearer if you gave the dynamical system (if you have one).

Comment: why you assume $X$ is non vanishing? If not, for example $X=-\nabla f$, where $f$ is a Morse function. There is a Laplacian-like operator, called Witten Laplatian, related the stable/unstale cells of the dynamical and the cohomology of maniflold.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Thanks  for  the comment.where is  a  proof of this  statement?is it elementary?What about the  algebra of diff operatores on $\Gamma TM$ generated by $\nabla_{X}$ or $[X,.]$?I seach  for  an operator associated with $X$ such that some interesting quantity of this operator can count the number of  attractors.

Comment: @shu thanks  for  your  information on Witten  Laplacian. My reason that  I  assumeed the  nonvanishing condition is the following; Some times ago a researcher suggested me to consider the  operator $D(U)=PU_{x}+QU_{y}+i(QU_{x}-PU_{y})$ as  complex  diff operator associated with vector  field $P\partial_{x}+Q\partial_{y}$. This  operator is elliptic  at **non singular points** of $X$. This  situation was my main motivation to  consider the  following  question.....

Comment: ... the  following question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/182139/lifting-a-quadratic-system-to-a-non-vanishing-vector-field-on-s3

Comment: @ Ali  Compute the principal symbol and notice it is not invertible. It vanishes for any covector $\xi$ such that $\xi(X)=0$.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu another  question: Am i right to think that the index of  every  operator  $D_{X}+\Delta$, the  same  operator which proposed byJoonas, is  zero where $D_{X}$ is the derivation operator

Comment: @ Ali Yes, the index is zero.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu  what type  of  **non**elliptic  operatores  are known to have  finite fredholm index?

Comment: On a compact  manifold  a partial differential operator is Fredholm if and only if it is elliptic.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu  thank you. May you give  a  reference?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu  and  what type  of  results  on non elliptic on non compact without  boundary?

Comment: You can find this in Theorem 5, Chapter IV of R. Seeley's memoir *Topics in pseudo-differential operators*. 1969 Pseudo-Diff. Operators (C.I.M.E., Stresa, 1968) pp. 167–305 Edizioni Cremonese, Rome

Comment: @ Ali You first need to understand    well   the meaning of ellipticity before you attack  more complicated issues.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu I think it is  a  linear  map $D$ on $\Gamma E$ for  which principle  symbole is  an invertible  bundle  morphism on $q^{*} E$ where $q:T^{*}M\to M$ is  the  natural projection. The  definition of  principle  symbol is  written clearly in Nakahara. Are you  meaning some other  complicated definition of  ellipticity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17655/discussion-between-liviu-nicolaescu-and-ali-taghavi).

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu for  a covector $\Xi$ and  a section $s$ $P(D)(\Xi,s)=D(1/n!fs)$ where $f$ is  a  function with $df=\Xi$. are you meaning some more complicated definition of ellipticity?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu  I enter the chat but I am not sure that it works. Did you received my message?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu  According to your  comment "On a compact manifold a partial differential operator is Fredholm if and only if it is elliptic"  what is  the  error  of  the  following  statement:Let $f:S^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ be  a  morse  function with exactly two  critical points  a  minimum at S  and  a  maximum at N(for example $f(x,y,z)=z$). Now  consider the  gradient  vector  field $X=\nabla f$. Now I think the derivational operator $D_{X}$  is  a  non elliptic  operator on $C^{\infty}(M)$ which is  a  fredholm operator(of  codimension 2 and the kernel is one  dimensional). Am I mistaken?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu  Now I reviewed your definition of symbol in your lecture on Atiyah singer index theorem.I have  a  question: you spend at  least one or two pages  to  define  the  symbol. it  seems  that you take it very  difficult. why  you do not simply define  the  symbol as in the  Nakahara  book or  in a paper of  of  Atiyah?(As  I  wrote in the  above  comments).  What is  the  advantage of your complicated  definition? Is there  a  real  application  and  a  motivation  for this  complication?

Comment: @AliTaghavi, I think the cokernel is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @ChrisGerig Are you considering the smooth function? That is : do you believe that the codimension is infinite if we consider the operator on smooth functions?

Comment: Yes; I think the spherical harmonics won't be in the image, because they can't be integrated (when solving for the corresponding function in the domain). For example, in order for $D_X(f)=\cos\phi$ you need $f=\sin^2\theta\ln|\sin\phi|$ which blows up at $\phi=0,\pi$.

Comment: @ChrisGerig But what is the error of the following argument which shows the codimension is "2"?: Let $g$ be  an smooth function with $g(N)=g(S)=0$ then $D_{X}(f)=g$  for  $f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(\phi_{t}(x))dt$  where $\phi$ is the flow of the vector field.$ Since the singularities are hyperbolic, then this integral is well defined(converges). In this [note](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408037) I tried to extend this idea to count the number of  limit cycles as a fredholm index. However there is  a gap in this not but a true (and weaker) version...

Comment: [is the second part of this note](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0001)

Comment: I don't know enough to turn this into an answer, but you might have a look at some of the stuff that symplectic geometers and low dimensional topologists are doing.  Some of their most powerful tools - like symplectic homology and Heegaard-Floer homology - are based on index theory for nonlinear Fredholm operators, and there are deep connections with dynamical systems.

Comment: I just want to reiterate what Liviu Nicolaescu has already said: Any PDO defined using only the vector field $X$ and no other PDEO is never elliptic. The best way to understand this is to look up the most general definition of an elliptic partial differential operator and test it against examples such as $\nabla_X$, $[X,\cdot]$, and any other example you can think of. Any PDO defined using only $X$ is essentially an ODE along the integral curves of $X$. If such an operator is Fredholm, it is due to the global dynamics of the operator and not a local property of the PDO such as ellipticity.

Comment: @PaulSiegel   Thanks for your very interesting  comment. I  do not know  why I did not realized your  comment. I did not received any announce for your comment.

Comment: @DeaneYang  Thanks for your very interesting  comment. I had the same problem with your comment as I explained above.Can I ask you to more explain on your last statement.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta  What about $\Delta +\partial^{2}/\partial X^{2}$? Is its index independent of choosing a vector field?Is it always elliptic?

Comment: @AliTaghavi, that is always elliptic but I don't know about the index off the top of my head.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu  Is the index of the operator in my previous comment independent of $X$?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta  any way your first comment on this question was very interesting  for me and that comment is a motiviation to this home genus second order operator.

Comment: Ali, I assumed that you wanted the PDO to be first order and the top order term to be $X$.

Comment: @DeaneYang According to my previous comment is the index of $\Delta +\epsilon \partial^{2}/\partial X^{2}$ independent of $X$ and $\epsilon$, hence $0$? So this operator is useless from dynamical view point?

Comment: @PaulSiegel  can I ask you to introduce me  a precise reference which need the minimum background.

Comment: A couple of quick little comments: 1) The operator $\Delta + \epsilon X^2$ depends not only on $X$ but on the Riemannian metric used to define $\Delta$. 2) Perhaps a better thing to look at is $X^2 + \epsilon^2 \Delta$ and ask what happens as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @DeaneYang  Do you mean the index of $\Delta+\epsilon X^{2}$  depends on $X$ and $\epsilon$? If yes, what is the mistake of the following argument. $\Delta=\epsilon X^{2}$ is  a  path of fredholm operator hence the index is fix.

Comment: @AliTaghavi For the last ten years, Bismut has been working on so-called hypoelliptic operators related to the geodesic spray on $T^*M$, see [http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~bismut/]. This is a manifold version of the Fokker-Planck equation, and it gives Fredholm operators. Maybe, you can set up similar operators on $M$ itself under nice assumptions on $X$?

Comment: @SebastianGoette  thank you for useful information.

Comment: @SebastianGoette  I sincerely thank you  very much. I just realize that there  are non elliptic operator  which are  Fredholm. I  confess that  I  did  not  pay  good  attention to  your  valuable  comments. Thanks  a  Lot. i  hope that it  works  for dynamical  interpretations for a vector  field.

Comment: @DeaneYang  Thank you  for  interesting  suggestion $X^2+ \epsilon \Delta$   It seems that the index is  unbounded when epsilon goes to zero.

Comment: @DeaneYang  because the  codimension of the  range  $X^2$ is  infinite in case  of  existence  of  at least two  attractors(either limit  cycle  or  singularity

Comment: Please  see the very  interesting  comment  by  Lukas  Geyer   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163800/elliptic-and-fredholm-partial-differential-operators

Comment: and  the  last  version of the  following    https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164059/codimension-of-the-range-of-certain-linear-operators

Comment: after  about  13  years  i  am still  wonder to  find  an  appropriate  operator  associated  to  a  vector  field whose index  or  other  quantities  can be  used to  count the  number of  limit  cycles

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta  I  found the Sibreg _Witten equation very similar to your idea. Can one  find some relations in this  contex? Thanks  again for  your  interesting  comment  https://www.physicsoverflow.org/41645/the-seiberg-witten-equations-for-vector-fields

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu  may I ask you to read the update version of this question?

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps you would be interested in Witten's proof of the Poincare-Hopf theorem.  Given a smooth nondegenerate vector field $V$ on a smooth closed manifold $M$, the theorem asserts that the Euler characteristic of $M$ is equal to the sum of the signs of the critical points of $V$.  Perhaps this isn't as interesting as the dynamical behavior that you mentioned in your question, but it's a start.

Witten's approach is to use $V$ to perturb the de Rham complex by replacing the de Rham differential $d$ with the operator

$$d_t = d + t i_v \colon\: \Omega^*(M) \to \Omega^*(M)$$

where $t$ is a real number and $i_V$ is the interior product with $V$.  He looked at the corresponding perturbed de Rham operator $D_t = d_t + d_t^*$ (where the adjoint is defined using a choice of Riemannian metric) and as usual viewed it as a graded Dirac-type operator on the graded Clifford module $\Omega^*(M)$.  $D_t$ is elliptic and hence Fredholm, and since the index of an operator is determined by its symbol class the index of $D_t$ is just the index of the usual de Rham operator $D$ which is the Euler characteristic of $M$.

On the other hand, one can calculate that
$$D_t^2 = D^2 + t^2 ||V||^2 + t T$$
where $T$ is some bundle map.  For large values of $t$ the potential term $t^2 ||V||^2$ becomes very large except in a tiny neighborhood of the critical set of $V$, so one can show that the eigenvectors of $D_t$ concentrate near the critical set.  Combining this observation with the McKean-Singer formula for the index of $D_t$ and some asymptotic analysis proves the Poincare-Hopf theorem.

There are a variety of generalizations of this result in the literature - perturbing other operators, relaxing the nondegeneracy assumption, etc.  I don't know this literature too well and so I don't quite know how much dynamics to expect, but it's worth a look.

Comment: I suppose this is actually quite similar to Yuri Bakhtin's answer, but perhaps the added focus on index theory will be helpful.

Comment: thank you very much for your interesting answer. I try to learn it.

Answer (score 7):

The following does not answer your question directly, but I could not resist writing it down.

Some interesting properties of $X$ will arise if you consider the operator $F_\epsilon(g)=D(g)+\epsilon\Delta g$ and let $\epsilon\to0$. (Here, $D$ is your $D$ and $\Delta$ is the Laplace--Beltrami or you can replace it with any other uniformly elliptic 2-nd order operator)

This has a probabilistic interpretation of adding a small noisy perturbation to the dynamical system and then letting the noise amplitude go to zero. Of course, over finite time intervals the perturbed dynamics converge to the unperturbed deterministic motion, but over infinite time horizon there are often interesting residual effects after "zeroing" the noise.

One keyword is "Freidlin--Wentzell theory".

Comment: Thank you very much for  your  answer. I try to  understand this interesting probabilistic interpretation you mentioned.