# A question on smooth sections of a vector bundle

Tags: vector-bundles

Let $E\to M$  be  a real  smooth  vector  bundle  and $N_{1},N_{2},\ldots,N_{k}$ are  disjoint  compact  (proper) submanifolds  of  $M$. Are there smooth sections  $s_{1},s_{2},\ldots,s_{k}$  such that for every nontrivial linear  combination $s=\sum \lambda_{i} s_{i}$ there exist an index $j\in \{1,2,\ldots,k\}$  such that $s$ is non  vanishing  on $N_{j}$? Note  that this is true when $E$ possess a  global non vanishing  section.

This  question is  indirectly  related to [The "Rolle theorem" for sections of a vector bundle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182682/the-rolle-theorem-for-sections-of-a-vector-bundle)