# Uniform upper bound for dim of kernel and codimension of range of certain familly of PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ds.dynamical-systems, elliptic-pde, differential-operators, index-theory

A polynomial vector field  of  degree $n$ on $S^{2}$ is  the  [Poincare compactification](http://www.scielo.cl/pdf/proy/v22n3/art01.pdf) of a $n$ degree polynomial vector  field on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.It is a real analytic vector field on $S^{2}$ which naturally  arises from a polynomial vector field on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

According to the  comment of  Joonas on [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182415/elliptic-operators-corresponds-to-non-vanishing-vector-fields)
, we  ask:

> Is  there uniform upper bound $IH(n)$, depending only on $n$,  for  the dimension of  kernel and  cokernel of the  elliptic  diff operator $D_{X} +\Delta$ on $S^{2}$  where $X$  is  a  polynomial  vector  field  of  degree $n$  on  $S^{2}$?