# When a PDE add a Laplacian term

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, elliptic-pde

I went to a talk today and the speaker mentioned when you add a Laplacian term to a PDE, the Laplacian will dominate (in what sense?), which I don't quite understand. I know this question is a bit vague but I appreciate if someone could clarify the question more.

Update: The speaker didn't actually mention specific pdes. He said it's more like a general "rule" or principle. Since he said it like a convention, I didn't have gut to ask him this question. I understand there are exceptions and I appreciate if there are common pdes that follow his "principle".

Comment: It would definitely depend on the context. Can you at the very least specify which equation you are talking about? For example, you can think of Navier-Stokes as "adding a Laplacian" to Euler's equations. That the regularity of Navier-Stokes is a Clay Problem is precisely because you cannot always say that the Laplacian will dominate!

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks! I just updated the question.

Comment: @qiewen  I  am interested in your question. Some  how I  encountered this  concept  in the  comment  conversation of  this  post:   https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182415/elliptic-operators-corresponds-to-non-vanishing-vector-fields?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: If you're looking for any example showing that adding a Laplacian term (even with a small coefficient) may change the game, see [Burgers' equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation). Googling "vanishing viscosity" might also be helpful.

Comment: Similarly, if you take a linear transport equation, it has hyperbolic nature. If you add a diffusive term, say $\epsilon\Delta$, then no matter how small $\epsilon>0$ is, the corresponing PDE will have parabolic nature. Understanding how the solutions to this regularized PDE converge as $\epsilon\to 0$ is a subtle issue, and all the more so if boundary conditios play a role (think of the number of necessary boundary conditions). On the other hand, if you perturb a bi-Laplacian $\Delta^2$ by a Laplacian, you surely won't get anything essentially different.