# On equation $\Delta \circ \partial/\partial X=\partial/\partial X \circ \Delta$ on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, laplacian

Assume that $M$ is  a compact Riemannian manifold whose  Laplacian is  denoted  by $\Delta$.  Assume  that the  Euler  characteristic of  $M$ is  zero. Does  $M$ admit a  non vanishing  vector  field  $X$ which satisfy $$(*) \qquad \Delta \circ \partial/\partial X=\partial/\partial X \circ \Delta$$

What  can be said  about the  structure of  the  Lie  algebra of  all  vector  fields $X$ with the property $(*)$?

**As  a  second  question:** Every  vector  field  $X$ on $M$ defines a second order differential operator  on $C^{\infty}(M)$  with $$D(f)=\Delta(X.f)-X.\Delta(f)$$

This  is a  second order operator  since the third order terms  cancel  each others.

What is  the principal symbol of this operator , precisely? Can this PDE  be an elliptic operator when $M$ is a compact manifold?(I mean:is there  an  example  of this  situation in compact case?) Does every  compact  manifold admit a vector  field $X$ for which this  PDE would be  an elliptic operator?What would  be a  dynamical interpretation for the  index of this PDE. [This  is  a  dynamical motivation for the later question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182415/elliptic-operators-corresponds-to-non-vanishing-vector-fields).

Comment: In $\mathbb R^n$, the laplacian is invariant under rotations. Did you try X= a killing vector?

Comment: @MarcoFarinati Thank you for your comment. I  need  to  know  the  remaining part of the  expersion  $\Delta(X.Y)=\Delta(X).Y+X.\Delta(Y)+2.....$. In fact the equation $*$ in the question defines  a  second  order PDE. I wish to know are there some example of compact  manifold for which this PDE is  elliptic?and  what is its  index  and the dynamical interpretation of this index. BTW is it obvious every manifold with  zero Euler characteristic admit a  non vanishing killing vector field?

Comment: In  my previous  comment, $X.Y$ is  the  inner product of two  vector  fields and  by laplacian of  a  vector  field  I am  considering the  Laplacian of the  corresponding 1-form. But I  wonder what is the  remaining part of  that  formula. i  wrote  down  in local coordinate  but  i  do not  know  what  is  the  global formula  in an  abstract  manifold?

Comment: The principal term is $\nabla^{(a} X^{b)} \nabla_{a} \nabla_{b}$, where the parentheses denote symmetrization. So this commutator is as elliptic as the $\nabla_{(a} X_{b)}$ bilinear form is positive definite. Up to a constant, the last expression also happens to be the Lie derivative of the Riemannina metric $g_{ab}$ with respect to $X$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following formula is known among the experts but hard to find in the literature, so I figure I will document it here. Throughout $(M,g)$ denote an arbitrary *pseudo-Riemannian* manifold, and $\nabla$ its Levi-Civita connection.

> **Definition** Given a vector field $X$, its corresponding *0th order deformation tensor* is defined to be ${}^{(X,0)}\pi := \mathcal{L}_X g$, where $\mathcal{L}_X$ is Lie differentiation with respect to $X$.
>   The corresponding *1st order deformation tensor* is defined using a formula similar to that of Christoffel symbols:
>   $$ {}^{(X,1)}\pi_{ab}{}^c := \frac12 g^{cd} \left[ \nabla_a ( {}^{(X,0)}\pi_{bd}) + \nabla_b ({}^{(X,0)}\pi_{ad}) - \nabla_d ({}^{(X,0)}\pi_{ab}) \right] $$
>
> **Lemma** Let $\Xi$ be an arbitrary $k$-covariant tensor field. And let $X$ be a vector field. The following formula holds for the commutation:
>   $$ [ \nabla_a, \mathcal{L}_X ] \Xi_{b_1\cdots b_k} = \sum_{j = 1}^k {}^{(X,1)}\pi_{a b_j}{}^c \Xi_{b_1 \cdots b_{j-1} c b_{j+1} \cdots b_k} $$

With the aid of these formulas, we have immediately that, writing $\triangle_g$ for the Laplace-Beltrami operator, first

$$ [ \nabla_X, \triangle_g] f = [\mathcal{L}_X, \triangle_g ] f $$

because Lie derivation and covariant differentiation act identically on scalars, and then

$$ [\mathcal{L}_X, g^{ab}\nabla_a\nabla_b] f = \mathcal{L}_X (g^{ab}) \nabla^a \nabla_b f + g^{ab} [\mathcal{L}_X, \nabla_a] \nabla_b f + g^{ab} \nabla_a [\mathcal{L}_X, \nabla_b ]f $$

The first factor we can compute to get

$$ \mathcal{L}_X(g^{ab}) = - {}^{(X,0)}\pi^{ab} $$

using that $g^{ab} g_{bc} = \delta^a_c$. The third factor vanishes because Lie differentiation commutes with exterior differentiation. And we use our Lemma for the second term. We get, finally

$$ [\nabla_X, \triangle_g] f = - {}^{(X,0)}\pi^{ab} \nabla_a\nabla_b f - g^{ab} ~{}^{(X,1)}\pi_{ab}{}^c \nabla_c f. $$

Remarks:

- Notice that the first order deformation tensor is defined in terms of the 0th order one. So that when $X$ is Killing, automatically both the ${}^{(X,0)}\pi$ and ${}^{(X,1)}\pi$ vanish, and differentiation with $X$ commutes with the Laplacian.
- In the case ${}^{(X,0)}\pi = \phi g$ for some scalar function $\phi$ (so $X$ is conformally Killing), one can check that the formula reduces to [the one I gave in a comment above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334060/on-equation-delta-circ-partial-partial-x-partial-partial-x-circ-delta#comment835997_334130).
- When the function $\phi$ in the previous item is a non-zero constant (which some people refer to as $X$ being a *homothetic vector field*) one gets the special case
  $$ [ \nabla_X, \triangle_g] f = \phi \triangle_g f $$

Comment: Thank you very much and +1 for your answer. I try to understand its details.

Answer (score 6):

This is an expansion on Igor's comment and fixes my previous mistake (see also Willie's answer).  A direct computation gives
$$ D(f) = 2f^{ab}\nabla_{(a}X_{b)} + X_a(\nabla^b\nabla_b\nabla^a-\nabla^a\nabla_b\nabla^b)f + f^a\nabla^b\nabla_bX_a . $$
The middle summand is the same as $R_{ab}f^a$, while the formula $\nabla^b\nabla_aX_b=\nabla_a\nabla^bX_b+R_a{}^bX_b$ yields
$$ D(f) = 2f^{ab}\nabla_{(a}X_{b)} + (\nabla^b\nabla_bX_a + \nabla^b\nabla_aX_b - \nabla_a\nabla^bX_b)f^a . $$
This can be rewritten
$$ D(f) = \langle L_Xg, \nabla^2f \rangle + \langle \nabla f, \delta L_Xg - d\delta X\rangle , $$
which easily gives the formula for $D$ when $X$ is a conformal Killing field.  The interpretations for your questions are as follows:

*Case 1*: $\nabla_{(a}X_{b)}$ is not identically zero.  This is when $D$ is a second-order operator.  Note that the trace of $\nabla_{(a}X_{b)}$ is the divergence. By the divergence theorem, the integral of the trace is zero, so the bilinear form $\nabla_{(a}X_{b)}$ cannot be positive definite.  Thus there is no example of the type requested in your second question.  (Note that on noncompact manifolds there are examples: e.g. Euclidean space with the Euler vector field $X=\sum x^i\partial_{x^i}$, so $D$ is proportional to the Laplacian.)

*Case 2*: $\nabla_{(a}X_{b)}\equiv0$.  (That is, $X$ is Killing.)  Since the trace of $L_Xg$ is $2\delta X$, we see that $D\equiv0$.  That is, the Lie algebra of vector fields satisfying ($\ast$) is the Lie algebra of Killing vector fields.

Comment: Thank you very much and +1 for your answe I  will come back soon.

Comment: I  would  appreciate if  you  more  explain about "If X is parallel and nonvanishing, then (M,g) splits off a flat factor in the direction of X"

Comment: As  another question: is there a  vector field  $X$ on the plane which  possess  a  closed orbit  $\gamma$  and there is  a  function $f$  such that $D(f)$ is  a  non vanishing  function on $\gamma$  and  its  interior?($D(f)$  is   the  same  operator  as in the  question and  laplacian is the  standard one). what  about if  we replace the  Laplacian  by  a laplacian  associated to  a  metric  compatible  to flow of X?

Comment: I edited the answer to include a reference to a more complete answer to your first question.  For your new question in the comments, $D(1)=0$ for any Riemannian manifold and any vector field.

Comment: The computation doesn't seem entirely correct: $$\nabla^b \nabla_b (Xf) = 2(\nabla^b X^a)( \nabla_b \nabla_a f)+ X^a \nabla^b \nabla_b \nabla_a f + (\nabla^b \nabla_b X^a) \nabla_a f $$ your answer contains the first and third term. The middle term is **not** $X(\nabla^b \nabla_b f)$! The two differ by a commutation of $[\nabla^b \nabla_b, \nabla_a]$ which introduces another curvature term. For Killing vector fields (and conformal Killing ones also) this term actually completely cancels the Ricci curvature term.

Comment: In fact, when $X$ is conformal Killing (so $\mathcal{L}_X g = \phi g$ for some function $\phi$), the commutator can be computed to be $$ [ X, \triangle_g]f = - \phi \triangle_gf + \frac{d-2}{2} g(\nabla \phi, \nabla f) $$ ($d$ is the dimension of the manifold). The expression in the general case is slightly more involved.

Comment: Oops, Willie is of course correct.  My answer has been fixed.