# Dynamical obstruction for a vector field to have a Harmonic divergence

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

> Let $(M,g)$  be  an analytic  Riemannian manifold and  $X$ be an analytic vector  field on $M$. Can we always  have  a  volume form $\Omega$  such that $\operatorname{Div}_{\Omega} X$ is  a harmonic  function with respect to the Riemannian metric $g$?  What about the  particular case $E^n$ the  standard Riemannian structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$?
> We  do not  require any compatibility or  relation between the  metric  $g$ and  volume form $\Omega$.

To  have  such  a  compatibility we  may modify the  question to have a  similar  question as  follows:

> Let $X$ be an analytic vector  field on a manifold $M$. Is  there  a  Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$ with associated  volume form $\Omega_g$  such that the  divergence of  $X$  with respect to $\Omega_g$ is  a  harmonic function?

**Added:** Regarding the  first question in dimension 1,  assume that  $X$ is  a vector  field on the  real line  with the  usual metric.  The  Harmonic  functions in this setting  are just affine linear maps. If  we  multiply the  standard volumeform $\Omega=dx$  by a  non vanishing function $f$ then the question is  equivalent  to  find a  function $f$  such that $fX'+f'X$  would  be  a linear map. So $fX$ must be  a  quadratic map. So this  gives a restriction on the  dynamic: The  vector  field  $X$ can not have more than 2 simple singularities. So this is possiby a promising simple  case which can motivate some  non trivial and possibly interesting dynamical obstruction for  existence of  a  volume form for  which the  divergence of $X$ would be  a harmonic map. On the other hand if a smooth  vector  field $X$ on the real line  has  at most  2 singularities  which are of  simple type, say at $a$, $b$,  then  we may put $f=\frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{X}$. Then $fX$ is a  quadratic map.So the  answer is  affirmative in 1  dimensional case:  We can have  a volume  form with that property if the  vector  field  has  at most two  equilibrium points. So  we  hope that the  Harmonic  requirement of this  question generates interesting  and non trivial  dynamical obstruction.  For  instance  what  would be the  obstruction in dimension 2?

**It seems that the quantity and  the  number of  dynamical objects come to play.**

For  some  other kind of  dynamical  obstructions please see the  following my past  post:

[Elliptic operators corresponds to non vanishing vector fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182415/elliptic-operators-corresponds-to-non-vanishing-vector-fields)